# Named parameter in JPQL

Tags: jpa, jpql

I am writing a JPQL query. There is a having clause .

"HAVING COUNT(TC.id) = 5"

But now it turned out that instead of 5 in a special case I have to compare it to 4. So the query would be

"HAVING COUNT(TC.id) = 4"

Of course I do not want to duplicate code. So what I thought I introduce a variable. Like this.

Page funk(@Param("number")Integer number);

So now my query would look like

"HAVING COUNT(TC.id) = number"

But somehow JPQL does not support this. What should I do .

Comment: It should be `= :number`.

Comment: Hm ok. I was thinking this again is not supported because JPQL also does not support subselect after select or from. So I started having doubts if this again is not supported. But thanks.